# Change default colors set on Angular ngx-charts

Tags: css, angular, ngx-charts

I'm working on an angular app and using ngx-charts, after debugging and searching online for few moments I couldn't find how to change the color palette on the charts.

The default angular color palette looks like the following: 
[image]

Do you guys know how to change the color palette on the ngx-charts?

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 11):

For newer version above 19 . They changed their structure . You can give name of color scheme from [here](https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-charts/#/ngx-charts/bar-vertical)  and example usage will be

```
 <ngx-charts-pie-chart
          [view]="view"
          [scheme]="'forest'"
          [results]="single"
          [legend]="showLegend"
          [explodeSlices]="explodeSlices"
          [labels]="showLabels"
          [doughnut]="doughnut"
          [gradient]="gradient"
          (select)="onSelect($event)">
   </ngx-charts-pie-chart>
```

but if you want to use custom colors then u need to use   `[customColors]` attribute and its format is like

```
{ name: "", value: '#33cc33' }
```

here you need to be sure that  name of color and name of data object need to be same. For example your data is like `[{name="Turkey",value:100}]` then your color object need to be `[{name="Turkey",value: '#33cc33'}]`

Answer (score 6):

After debugging for a while I found the solution:

So here are the steps:

Step 1 : On my .ts file I added a variable with the colors I needed

```
colorScheme = {
    domain: ['#5AA454', '#A10A28', '#C7B42C', '#AAAAAA']
  };
```

Step 2: on the .html file I called that variable inside the            [scheme]="colorScheme" Property

```
<ngx-charts-pie-chart
          [results]="chartData.pieChartData.chartPoints"
          [legend]="chartData.chartOptions.showLegend"
          [explodeSlices]="chartData.chartOptions.explodeSlices"
          [labels]="true"
          **[scheme]="colorScheme"**
          [tooltipDisabled]="!chartData.chartOptions.showToolTip"
          [doughnut]="chartData.chartOptions.donut"
          aria-hidden="true">
        </ngx-charts-pie-chart>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to mr pc coder's answer.

Just to clarify, In your **template** make sure to use `customColors` like so:

```html
 <ngx-charts-bar-vertical 
  [customColors]="barChartcustomColors"
  [view]="view"
  [results]="barChartData"
  [legend]="true"
  [legendPosition]="below"
  [showGridLines]="showGridLines"
  [showXAxisLabel]="true"
  [showYAxisLabel]="true"
  [xAxis]="true"
  [yAxis]="true">
</ngx-charts-bar-vertical>
```

In your component, make sure to declare the custom colours like so:

```js
  barChartcustomColors = 
  [
    { name: "2019", value: '#febb00' },
    { name: "2020", value: '#1dd068' },
    { name: "2021", value: '#1dd068' },
    { name: "2022", value: '#febb00' },
  ]

  barChartData = [
    { name: "2019", value: 30 },
    { name: "2020", value: 60 },
    { name: "2021", value: 96 },
    { name: "2022", value: 151 },
  ];
```

Note that I used the variable `barChartcustomColors` which has been used in the HTML template as well as the TS component.

So just make sure your data *name* keys match the colour *name* keys word for word, as any typo would not make it render.

Answer (score 2):

Use colorScheme variable can custom your chart color. You can find description in doc.

https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-charts/examples/pie-charts/pie-chart

> custom colors for the chart. Used to override a color for a specific value

[example pie chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPjKK.png)

src/app.ts

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser-animations';
import {NgxChartsModule} from '@swimlane/ngx-charts';
import {single, multi} from '../data.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <ngx-charts-pie-chart
      [view]="view"
      [scheme]="colorScheme"
      [results]="single"
      [legend]="showLegend"
      [explodeSlices]="explodeSlices"
      [labels]="showLabels"
      [doughnut]="doughnut"
      [gradient]="gradient"
      (select)="onSelect($event)">
    </ngx-charts-pie-chart>
  `
})
export class App {
  single: any[];

  // chart area size
  view: any[] = [700, 400];

  // options
  showLegend = false;
  showLabels = true;
  explodeSlices = false;
  doughnut = false;

  // your color scheme
  colorScheme = {
    domain: [
      '#FF8A80', 
      '#EA80FC',
      '#8C9EFF', 
      '#80D8FF', 
      '#A7FFEB', 
      '#CCFF90', 
      '#FFFF8D', 
      '#FF9E80'
    ]
  };

  constructor() {
    Object.assign(this, {single})   
  }

  // select event
  onSelect(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }

}


@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, NgxChartsModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

data.ts

```
export var single = [
  {
    "name": "Apple",
    "value": 8940000
  },
  {
    "name": "Banana",
    "value": 5000000
  },
  {
    "name": "Ornage",
    "value": 7200000
  },
  {
    "name": "Avocado",
    "value": 4830200
  },
  {
    "name": "Cherry",
    "value": 5520000
  },
  {
    "name": "Coconut",
    "value": 1200000
  },
  {
    "name": "Guava",
    "value": 2230000
  },
  {
    "name": "Lemon",
    "value": 4323000
  }
];
```